# Lane information doesn't show in Here Map

Tags: java, android, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk, heremap-navigation

I am working in an app with maps using Here Maps but when the navigation launchs, the lane information doesn't show. I am following this example --> https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/tree/master/advanced-navigation/app/src/main/java/com/here/android/example/advanced/navigation 
I have tried debbug mode but it doesn't enter in LaneInfoUtils.java.
There is a error in the log, I don't know if it's related.

```
D/EgretLoader: EgretLoader(Context context)
    The context is not activity
W/cr_AwContents: Application attempted to call on a destroyed WebView
    java.lang.Throwable
        at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.r(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-447212033:2)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.addJavascriptInterface(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-447212033:6)
        at android.webkit.WebView.addJavascriptInterface(WebView.java:1924)
        at miui.contentcatcher.sdk.utils.WebViewUtils$NativeWebViewUtils.addJavascriptInterface(WebViewUtils.java:245)
        at miui.contentcatcher.sdk.utils.WebViewUtils.initWebViewJsInterface(WebViewUtils.java:158)
        at miui.contentcatcher.InterceptorProxy$1.run(InterceptorProxy.java:190)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8060)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
W/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: callback not found for CALLBACK_AVAILABLE message
W/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: callback not found for CALLBACK_AVAILABLE message
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with the Lane information as well. I ended up just going with the Realistic view, this shows a 2d image that shows you which lane you should take.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.18/dev_guide/topics/map-guidance-events.html

Go to the link provided and scroll down to Realistic View. This will give you more information on how to implement it. I was able to get it working with the code provided in the docs, I didn't have to put the images on the app itself like I did with just the Lane Information.